# Wrong unicode characters representation in Python 3.4 and py2exe-3

Tags: unicode, py2exe, python-3.4

I have problem with Unicode strings in frozen app. I use python 3.4.1 32bit (on Windows 7 64bit Pro) and [py2exe-3 from svn repository](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/py2exe/svn/trunk/py2exe-3/). I can demonstrate it with following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# file: test_py2exe.py

import sys

my_string = u"""This is a test:
ábc
End of test..."""

filename = 'test.txt'
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    filename = 'test-frozen.txt'

f = open(filename,  mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(my_string)
f.close()
```

If I run in standard python shell (py test_py2exe.py) the second line in test.txt is like this (correct):

> ábc

If I create frozen app with

```
py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe test_py2exe.py
```

and run 'dist\test_py2exe.exe' I have in test-frozen.txt second line like this:

> Ăˇbc

This problem is not related to storing strings to file only, but also when I use other modules (e.g. PyQt5, xlsxwriter) with unicode strings. Following instruction on [EvenMoreEncodings](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/EvenMoreEncodings) does not help... Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If it helps a clue is the corrupted string is UTF-8 mis-decoded as `windows-1250` (Central and Eastern Europe).  What language is your Win7 system configured in?  Also, how are you viewing the text file?  It may help to encode with the so-called UTF-8 BOM by using `encoding='utf-8-sig'` instead.  Windows editors tend to assume the current locale instead of UTF-8 unless the BOM is present.

Comment: I know problem is corrupted UTF-8. The issue is not it text editor where I check file (btw it is notepad++, but the same is in internal viewer of total commander). I recognized problem pyQT5 - in statusbar or QTextedit. If I run my app in python - everything was correct. But when I froze my app with py2exe-3 UTF-8 strings are mis-decoded...

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround that produce the same result in script and frozen app: `my_string.encode('cp1250').decode('utf-8')`. So updated code will look like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import sys
    import locale

    my_string = u"""This is a test:
    ábc
    End of test..."""
    filename = 'test.txt'
    sys_enc = sys.getdefaultencoding()  # 'utf-8'
    locale_enc = locale.getpreferredencoding()  # 'cp1250'

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        filename = 'test-frozen.txt'
        my_string = my_string.encode(locale_enc).decode(sys_enc)

    f = open(filename,  mode='w', encoding=sys_enc)
    f.write(my_string)
    f.close()
```